# How to get highest resolution version of thumbnail image? - YouTube API 3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get the highest resolution version of the thumbnail image for videos I'm downloading based on location. However I run into this error: **KeyError: 'maxres'**. Relevant portion of the code below:

```
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
      thumbnail = search_result["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["maxres"]["url"]
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a null checker to your code?

Comment: I haven't - will try that!

Comment: Not all videos have maxres thumbnails....

Comment: did you solve this problem, if can you mention here